# memory access vs. memory copy

Tags: c++, performance, memory

I am writing an application in C++ that needs to read-only from the same memory many times from many threads. 
My question is from a performance point of view will it be better to copy the memory for each thread or give all threads the same pointer and have all of them access the same memory.

Thanks

Comment: The obvious question is: is this memory constant while it is being read, or is it subject to changes ?

Comment: @Mysticial, one would hope that all architectures efficiently handle multiply read data, not just a NUMA system.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant: What you assume for your answers would be perhaps better confined to your answers (and stating your assumptions at the start of your answer is better, makes it easier for people reading them). However, I do not really care about your assumption *here*; the question is targeted at the OP (not you) because we need the OP to clarify.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: I think the point is that on a NUMA system there might be a benefit to having a local copy at each node, whereas there would probably be no benefit to having multiple copies if memory access were uniform.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, I just meant to indicate that though the memory architecture is relevant whether it is NUMA or not is probably not. Both SMP/NUMA (and likely others) tend to use local caches on data currently being used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no definitive answer from the little information you have given about your target system and so on, but on a normal PC, most likely the fastest will be to not copy.

One reason copying could be slow, is that it might result in cache misses if the data area is large. A normal PC would cache read-only access to the same data area very efficiently between threads, even if those threads happen to run on different cores.

One of the benefits explicitly listed by Intel for their approach to caching is ["Allows more data-sharing opportunities for threads running on separate cores that are sharing cache"](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/software-techniques-for-shared-cache-multi-core-systems/). I.e. they encourage a practice where you don't have to program the threads to explicitly cache data, the CPU will do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you specifically mention many threads, I assume you have at least a multi-socket  system. Typically, memory banks are associated to processor sockets. That is, one processor is "nearest" to its own memory banks and needs to communicate with the other processors memopry controllers to access data on other banks. (Processor here means the physical thing in the socket)

When you allocate data, typically a first-write policy is used to determine on which memory banks your data will be allocated, which means it can access it faster than the other processors.

So, at least for multiple processors (not just multiple cores) there should be a performance improvement from allocating a copy at least for every processor. Be sure, to allocate/copy the data with every processor/thread and not from a master thread (to exploit the first-write policy). Also you need to make sure, that threads will not migrate between processors, because then you are likely to lose the close connection to your memory.

I am not sure, how copying data for every thread on a single processor would affect performance, but I guess not copying could improve the ability to share the contents of the higher level caches, that are shared between cores.

In any case, benchmark and decide based on actual measurements.